# No known class method for selector 'indexPathForRow:inSection:'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to import/use [this](https://github.com/austinzheng/iOS-2048) project in my Swift application, but the compiler throws tons of error with following message:

> No known class method for selector 'indexPathForRow:inSection:'

Following is the typical code which generates the above error:

```
if ([self tileForIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:i]].empty) {
...
}
```

I can able to run the downloaded project as an standalone application without having any problem, though.

I've also added all the frameworks to my main application - those were used and installed to the said project, but that didn't help. My main project's deployment target is 10.0.

Comment: It's a Swift application you're building, but that code is Objective-C. Are you sure you have the bridging headers in your project?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Objc-bridge and imported the main class file from the project - #import "F3HNumberTileGameViewController.h"

Comment: The error is because of `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:i]]` NSIndexPath's function `indexPathForRow:row` has to be called on an instance variable. it cant be called like a class/static function

Comment: But this is the exact copy of code files from the project. I'm wondering how this works there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexPathForRow:inSection:` is a static constructor method that creates NSIndexPath instances. It is defined in UIKit:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsindexpath/1614934-indexpathforrow?language=objc

In this project the author imports UIKit in the pch file:

https://github.com/austinzheng/iOS-2048/blob/7c0840a0f7bd77b01d6a36778a253f8f4b2e6529/NumberTileGame/NumberTileGame/NumberTileGame-Prefix.pch#L14

So you have 2 options: either setup a pch file for Objective-C code in your project (create the file and add to Xcode project build settings), or in each source file where you get this error add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the #import statement fixed all the compiler errors! Thank you for pointing to this. I tried to add UIKit.framework earlier to my project explicitly, but that didn't helped.

Comment: Nice. If you are making a UI app the UIKit is likely already there, in any case it affects linking, and #import affects compiling (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work )